# returning bulk data

Tags: solidity, contract-design

So I was wondering If it's possible to return bulk data. What I mean with that is returning everything (or part) from an array.
I know the following is not possible (correct me if I'm wrong)

- Array of strings
- Dynamic sized array
- Multi dimensional array
- Range of a mapping
- All keys of a mapping

So let's say I have a contract that saves multiple participants of a bingo. How can I return all the participants of the bingo.